# How to replace an ASP.NET XML WebControl so at use XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Currently I have some legacy ASP.NET 2.0 code that uses the ASP Xml web control like this:

```
<asp:Xml ID="XmlResult" runat="server" />
```

This is used to perform an XSLT transformation in c# code-behind like this:

```
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xslt/MyXsltFile.xslt"));
XmlResult.Transform = xslt;
XmlResult.TransformArgumentList = xslArgs; // these are created elsewhere

XmlResult.XPathNavigator = xd.CreateNavigator(); // xd is an XmlDocument()
```

The problem is that the ASP XML control expects an [XltTransform object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) and this is deprecated (marked as obsolete) as from NET 2.0:

> "The XslTransform class is obsolete in
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework version
>   2.0. The XslCompiledTransform class is the new XSLT processor."

However, I can't seem to figure out how to replace this to use an [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) object. Obviously you can just give XmlResult.Transform property an XslCompiledTransoform object as this won't work. So presumably will have to replace the ASP Xml control with something else? A Literal? A Placeholder? But then what...? I just can't seem to work out the best way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out this and thought I'd provide the answer in case it proves useful to others. Below is a small helper class that uses XsltCompiledTransform and also can cache the results. It was written specifically for caching Umbraco macros, but can be used in any situation, I believe.

```
public static class XsltHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a compiled XSLT transform object for an XSLT file and caches it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="XsltFile">The relative path to the XSLT file</param>
    /// <returns>An XslCompiledTransform object for the XSLT file</returns>
    public static XslCompiledTransform GetXslt(string XsltFile)
    {
        string cacheKey = "macroXslt_" + XsltFile;

        if (System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
        {
            return (XslCompiledTransform)System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        }
        else
        {
            return GetXSLT(XsltFile, cacheKey);
        }
    }

    private static XslCompiledTransform GetXSLT(string XsltFile, string cacheKey)
    {
        XslCompiledTransform macroXSLT = new XslCompiledTransform();

        using (XmlTextReader xslReader = new XmlTextReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(XsltFile)))
        {
            try
            {
                xslReader.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities;
                XmlUrlResolver xslResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
                xslResolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
                settings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
                settings.EnableScript = true;
                macroXSLT.Load(xslReader, settings, xslResolver);

                System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, macroXSLT,
                    new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(XsltFile)));
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return macroXSLT;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is a helper function from [my library on CodePlex](http://songhaydata.codeplex.com/) that might help you:

```
public static string GetXslString(IXPathNavigable xslSet, XsltArgumentList xslArgs, IXPathNavigable navigableSet)
{
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
        xslt.Load(xslSet);

        string ret = null;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xslt.Transform(navigableSet, xslArgs, ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            ret = XmlUtility.GetText(ms);
        }
        return ret;
}
```